# Adding Counter at the end of duplicate column names in csv

Tags: vb.net

I have a csv file  having say  50 columns. **its not always the case that all these column names are unique.** so converting this in to a data table is not possible some times directly.

so my idea is ,

1. ignore column names and read csv
2. get first row (which are actually column names) .
3. convert it into a list of string .
4. find duplicates from this list. lets say i have 5 duplicates

below is the algorithm which will do the job  , before that `counter shuld be -1`

```
 for all dupe in duplicate items 
   {
    for all str in string array 
     {
         if (str is eq to  dupe)
              counter = counter + 1 
         if counter > 0 
             str = str + counter
       }
    }
```

Now write back in to the csv Row(0) with new string array.
then change the column names of the data table as Row(0) and now delete the first row.

i know this is extremely in-efficient.  can some one suggest a better way ?

Comment: "Extremely inefficient" depends on context; something like this, which looks like a one-time routine, can probably withstand some inefficiency without a significant impact on your end-user.  However, if you want to improve upon it, I'd suggest using a `Dictionary(Of String, Integer)` to map duplicated column names to current count.  Then you could run just the inner loop.

Comment: If you want to code-golf it, you might even be able to make up a Linq expression that would convert your column headings at one go, but I'd avoid that because it's likely to be close to write-only code.

Comment: u mean to say  that efficiency of LINQ expressions are as same as the code we write ?

Comment: Sometimes better, sometimes worse, it depends on what you're doing with them.  They're worth doing when they make your code clearer and easier to maintain.  They're not worth doing when they make your code more complicated or when profiling shows they're a performance bottleneck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to find the duplicate column names just assign a number at the end of each field name. I used the `TextFieldParser` class. Available in Namespace: Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser?view=netcore-3.1

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim TFP As New TextFieldParser("C:\Users\maryo\Desktop\TestCSV.csv")
    TFP.Delimiters = {","}
    Dim FieldNames = TFP.ReadFields
    For i = 0 To FieldNames.Length - 1
        FieldNames(i) &= i.ToString
    Next
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    For Each FieldName In FieldNames
        dt.Columns.Add(FieldName)
    Next
    While Not TFP.EndOfData
        Dim currentRow = TFP.ReadFields()
        dt.Rows.Add(currentRow)
    End While
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

Comment: To be honest this is a actually a simpler solution. i will try to implement this today and close this thread. thanks :)